# Running a remote protractor webdriver manager doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, protractor

We are trying to run a test suite through the protractor chrome web driver,
all the tests ran successfully manually on our CI server (windows server 2012).

But when we run the protractor web driver manager through a service the tests get stuck in the middle of their work without any error information.

We suspect it has something to do with the chrome ran by the web driver 'GUI-less', but couldn't find really the root of the problem.

Is there something we missing ? like a special parameter the web driver should be started with when running without the GUI?

Comment: What browser?  (There is a bug with Firefox v35 that causes webdriver to hang.  See https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1734)

Comment: Its on chrome, but the thing is it works when running the webdriver manually. It hangs only when the web driver started remotely